# Create Airflow Dag of Dags keyed off unique ID

Tags: airflow

Im trying to create a Dag of Dags in airflow using `TriggerDagRunOperator` and `ExternalTaskSensor`:

```
    trigger_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='dag_name'
    )

    wait_dag = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id="wait_dag",
        external_dag_id="dag_name",
        execution_date_fn=execution_date_fn,
    )

    trigger_dag >> wait_dag
```

Currently `execution_date_fn` looks like this:

```
def get_most_recent_dag_run(dag_id, dag_run_id):
    dag_runs = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
    dag_runs.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=True)
    return dag_runs[0] if dag_runs else None


def execution_date_fn(execution_date, dag, task, **kwargs):
    dag_run = get_most_recent_dag_run(task.external_dag_id)
    dag_execution_date = dag.start_date if dag_run is None else dag_run.execution_date
    return pendulum.instance(dag_execution_date)
```

Because `ExternalTaskSensor` only works with scheduled runs and not triggered runs, I have to settle for the most recent dag run that is triggered. However, is there a way to pass in a unique ID into the triggered dag and then pull that back in with ExternalTaskSensor (via `execution_date_fn` probably)? I am a little confused how to send and receive xcoms between dags and couldnt see a way to get a xcom value set in the primary dag into a dag subtask (either `start` or `end` task).

It has to be a unique ID (and not an execution date) because I need to enable manual triggers of the connected pipeline that may have the same execution date. But It should also be extendable to running a daily pipeline where one day may fail, and I want to re-run that day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting the wait_dag task to simply find the DAG run that was triggered by trigger_dag, your best bet is probably to simply add the `wait_for_completion=True` option to TriggerDagRunOperator, so the task will be both trigger and sensor in one.

You may also want to look into [Data Aware Scheduling](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/datasets.html#data-aware-scheduling) and specifically the [micro-pipelines pattern](https://www.astronomer.io/blog/micropipelines-a-microservice-approach-for-dag-authoring-in-apache-airflow/) as an alternative to a DAG of DAGs.

Answer (score 0):

per the 2.8.2 version docs the TriggerDagRunOperator has the *conf*
parameter that can be passed to the triggered_dag.

```
    trigger_dag = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_dag',
        trigger_dag_id='dag_name',
        conf={"param1": "value1"}
    )
```

It also has a *wait_for_completion* and *poke_interval* if you want to wait in the Triggering DAG.
If you don't want to wait for the DAG's completion, you can always write a custom Success callback for the triggered_dag and fetch the conf parameters

```html
def success(context):
    try:
        params = context.get('params')
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/trigger_dagrun.html#TriggerDagRunOperator